# How I stop ploting a line when it hits a Candlebody

Tags: pine-script

I try to stop ploting a line when it Hits a Candlebody.
Right now it goes all the way through but it should stop to get plot when it hit the Candlebody.
I guess the "na" must get changed

```
plot(enableTP and dir == 1 ? longExitPrice : na, "Long Take Profit", linewidth=2, color=TPcolor, style = plot.style_linebr)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot :)

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your full code. If you decide to share your full code, please also upload a screenshot of your whole chart. So that the ticker, timeframe and date are visible.

Comment: it's not about the full code, I only want to stop plot a line, when it hit a candlebody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a boolean to check if body has been reached, and from that point on the price would be na:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

number = 60

highPrice = close > open ? close : open
lowPrice = close > open ? open : close

var lineNotInCandleBody = true

if (number > highPrice or number < lowPrice) and lineNotInCandleBody
    lineNotInCandleBody := true
else 
    lineNotInCandleBody := false

number := lineNotInCandleBody ? number : na

plot(number)
```

Comment: I had to change "true" and "false" but now it work like a charm. Thank you !